# ClassNotFoundException Mvx.MvxListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying use `MvxListView` with `MvxAppCompatActivity`, but I always get:

> InflateException: Error inflating class Mvx.MvxListView
>   ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Mvx.MvxListView

Here is my axml:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.viniciusmaia.missaocarona"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/Toolbar" />

    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/teste"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:MvxBind="ItemsSource Usuarios;ItemClick UsuarioClickCommand"
        app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/usuarioitem"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Activity:

```cs
[Activity] 
public class UsuarioActivity : MvxAppCompatActivity<UsuarioViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.UsuarioView);            

        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        toolbar.Title = UsuarioMensagens.TITULO_Usuario;

        //SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

        ViewModel.Carregamento = new Carregamento(this);
        ViewModel.PreenchePagina();
    }
}
```

I tried use `Mvx.MvxListview` and  `MvxListView` like this post [Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Mvx.MvxListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967221/binary-xml-file-line-1-error-inflating-class-mvx-mvxlistview), but nothing works for me.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does your Setup class inherit from?

Answer (score 4):

`Mvx.MvxListView` mentioned in Alex's answer is a shortcut that is registered with the custom `Inflater` that does binding in MvvmCross. This means, if your `Setup` class does not tell where to look for `Mvx`, the shortcuts wont work.

In this case, I see you are using `MvxAppCompatActivity`, which comes from one of the Support packages. There is a separate Setup you inherit from there, which handles a lot of registration for you. It will also set up some tint aware views.

So in your Setup, you should inherit from [`MvxAppCompatSetup`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat/MvxAppCompatSetup.cs):

```
public class Setup : MvxAppCompatSetup
{
}
```

This should be enough to find `Mvx.MvxListView`. If it doesn't you can try adding more abbreviations by overriding `ViewNamespaceAbbreviations` in your Setup:

```
public class Setup : MvxAppCompatSetup
{
    ...

    protected override IDictionary<string, string> ViewNamespaceAbbreviations new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Mvx", "MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views"},
        {"MyViews", "My.Custom.Views"},
        // add more abbreviations here
    };
}
```

This will make MvvmCross look for views in `MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views` when you prefix them with `Mvx` in your axml files.

"Mvx" => "MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views" is a default one, and should work with any `BindingInflater` from both `MvxAppCompatSetup`, but also `MvxAndroidSetup`.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing `Mvx.MvxListView` in your axml file instead of `MvxListView`.

Also your `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.viniciusmaia.missaocarona"` should be actually `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

One more thing to double check is to make sure your Setup class derives from MvxAndroidSetup

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line on your LinearLayout

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.viniciusmaia.missaocarona"`

with this:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```