# How to implement Recycler View in MvvmCross using MvxRecyclerView

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In MvvmCross, I have an android listview within an activity that works.

I read somewhere that changing the listView to a recyclerView is as simple as changing MvxListView to MvxRecyclerView in my layout .axml file. Trying that gives me the following runtime exception:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Mvx.MvxRecyclerView
```

Is there anything that I have to do differently in the code behind or view model when using MvxRecyclerView? Below is my code.

Layout files:

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxRecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/words_listview"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/words_listview_row"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Words" />
</LinearLayout>
```

words_listview_row.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    p1:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView
        p1:text="Word name"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/headingTextView"
        p1:width="325dp"
        p1:textColor="#000000"
        p1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        p1:textSize="18sp"
        p1:paddingLeft="20dp"
        p1:paddingTop="15dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
    <TextView
        p1:text="Word meaning"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_below="@id/headingTextView"
        p1:id="@+id/detailTextView"
        p1:textColor="#8f949a"
        p1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        p1:textSize="16sp"
        p1:paddingLeft="20dp"
        p1:paddingRight="20dp"
        p1:paddingBottom="15dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Meaning" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

WordViewModel.cs

```
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using VocabBuilder.Core.Models;
using VocabBuilder.Core.Services.Interfaces;

namespace VocabBuilder.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class WordViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private IWordService _wordService;

        public MvxObservableCollection<Word> Words { get; set; }

        public WordViewModel(IWordService wordService)
        {
            Words = new MvxObservableCollection<Word>();

            _wordService = wordService;

            Words.ReplaceWith(_wordService.GetAllWords());
        }
    }
}
```

Codebehind/ WordView.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Views;
using VocabBuilder.Core.ViewModels;

namespace VocabBuilder.UI.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity(Label="Vocab Builder", MainLauncher=true)]
    public class WordView : MvxActivity<WordViewModel>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is my Setup.cs file:

```
using Android.Content;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Platform;

namespace VocabBuilder.UI.Droid
{
    public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
    {
        public Setup(Context applicationContext) : base(applicationContext)
        {
        }

        protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
        {
            return new Core.App();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing MvxActivity with MvxAppCompatActivity.

Comment: Please show your Setup.cs file. I bet you haven't registered it there.

Comment: @sJy I get the same error using MvxAppCompatActivity.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I added the Setup.cs file at the bottom. Do I have to add specific registration code for a recycler view?

Comment: I was able to use `<Mvx.MvxListView/>` but I had to use the full namespace in my AXML file for MvxRecyclerView.  Does `<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView/>` work instead of `<Mvx.MvxRecyclerView/>` ?

Comment: @TrevorBalcom Yes, using the full namespace for MvxRecyclerView worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ShaikatHaque - if you want to use the shorthand, see the answer from Cheesebaron here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39913945/2754727

Comment: @pnavk Thanks, that clears up everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I got RecyclerView to work easily after replacing MvxListView with MvxRecyclerView.  Not sure what the particular problem with your implementation is but i will give you the tidbits of mine and you can try it all out.

My RecyclerView lives in a Fragment inheriting from MvxFragment - a bit different than yours but should not be the determining factor.  Here are some Fragment snippets:

```
public class ListsFragment : MvxFragment<ListsViewModel>
{
   ...
   public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
      var view =  this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_listsfragment, null);   
      return view;
   }
   ...
}
```

Here is the axml for fragment_listsfragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_list"
    app:MvxBind="ItemsSource Lists; ItemClick ShowListItemsCommand" />
```

I do see a bit of difference in your ViewModel implementation - mine is like this:

```
public class ListsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  ...
  private readonly IListService _listService;
  private ObservableCollection<Models.List> _lists;

  public ObservableCollection<Models.List> Lists
  {
    get { return _lists; }
    set
    {
      _lists = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Lists);
    }
  }

  public MvxCommand<Models.List> ShowListItemsCommand
  {
    get
    {
      return new MvxCommand<Models.List>(selectedList =>
      {
        ShowViewModel<ListItemsViewModel>
                (new { listId = selectedList.Id });
      });
    }
  }
  ...
  public override async void Start()
  {
    base.Start();
    await InitializeAsync();
  }

  protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
  {
    await _listService.InitializeAsync();
    Lists = (await _listService.GetListsAsync())
            .ToObservableCollection();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.